# Multiple Rows with columns into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation below where I want to compress the rows and columns into one in oracle sql. I appreciate any feedback. Thank you in advance.

```
Situation:
EMPNO START FINISH
1       1     0
1       0     1
2       2     0
2       0     2
3       3     0
3       0     3

Target:
EMPNO START FINISH
1       1      1
2       2      2
3       3      3
```

[image]

Comment: Stop editing the question!

Comment: First of all, don't use reserved words for column names (`START` is a reserved word). Secondly, you haven't specified which row is a real "start". Is there a marker for that? Ie, why (start,stop) are not `(0,0)` for all EMPNO?

Comment: What do you mean by compress? I see a pattern in your example. Is that the case for all your data in table?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. You already got some comments on how to improve your question to make clearer what you are trying to achieve. In addition to simply posting your input and desired output, it is typically appreciated if you show at least some things that you have tried yourself, problems you have encountered etc. This shows that you have some effort to solve your problem by yourself and do not just hope that the community will do everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

For this data, you could do this:

```
select empno, max(start), max(finish)
from emp
group by empno;
```